# PHP store values to MySQL database from dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

Ok I have a dropdown list, and I'd like to store the chosen option to the database through a variable defined on the beginning of the code:

```
$campus_name = isset($_POST['campus']) ? asi($_POST['campus']) :"";
```

The code for the dropdown list is as follows:

```
<select name="campus" id="campus">
      <option>Choose</option>
      <option value="1">Belaruz</option>
      <option value="2">Normdale</option>
```

So how do I store that to the table campus using the variable $campus_name to store it?

Comment: We don't know how the table campus is made, and however this question can be easily answered by reading one of the 100,000 tutorials around to do PHP & MySQL altogether. The first three or four results on Google will give you an answer.

Comment: @Giacomo: RTFM or "Google it" is not a proper Stack Overflow answer. The question is well-formed and pertinent. It should be answered.

Comment: @David - I wouldn't call it a well formed question. Where's he having trouble? Does the OP know how to connect to the DB? Is the DB created? Does the table exist? Is he having a problem writing SQL? This is very vague and bordering on unanswerable without churning out a chapter's worth of text.

Comment: @David: you may be right but I think one doesn't help Sinner writing the 4-5 lines of code he's looking for, that are widely available from thousands of sources. Copy&paste != learn. You have to learn things and then ask if something is not clear, not pray for and then paste code given by people around trying to carry on with it. More, what happens if Sinner modifies the code w/o understanding it causing SQL injection? This is the RTFM case, really

Comment: (You've got an extra `>` in your `option` tag)

Comment: Thanks for the opinions. Answering some things: the table exists, database is created. I have a php website with a MySQL DB. "campus" is a varchar(255) table. I tried to Google, with no success. I'm on my way of learning PHP but for now I'd be satisfied to complete this task. I really am new to PHP and MySQL but not to programming so I can instinctively understand some things and will eventually understand the code. This website is an inherited project so I must make any changes myself, or hire a programmer (for witch I don't have the means right now). Thank you all for the patience and help.

Comment: @Sinnerシンネル nice comment :)
well i am also have the same problem if your problem is solved let me known :)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I had a table called campus and it only had one column. I would use the mysql_query command. I used arbitrary names in my example but I hope you get the picture.

```
$campus_name = isset($_POST['campus']) ? asi($_POST['campus']) :""; 
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','ID','Password');
mysql_select_db('College', $link);
mysql_query("insert into campus(campusID)values('$campus_name')");
```

Comment: -1 DANGER: SQL injection prone, unless asi() sanities $_POST["campus"] which is not granted. That's why RTFM is sometimes a good answer.

Comment: He doesn't know about security, because he didn't RTFM. He asked for ready-to-paste code, which means that he will take bad habits (like the one of not sanitizing strings), so you're not doing good for him. He'll paste your code and get its flawed script broken by some lamer.